# Deleting a Drupal 8 Content Type Field also Deletes all the Views linked to it... Undo?

Tags: views, 8, entities

So I deleted a Drupal 8 content type field and it also deleted the views that is associated with it. Is there an undo button?

[image]

Comment: `Is there an undo button?` You backup your site daily like all the other good developers do, right? ...

Comment: No, there is no 'undo' button. This is a known core issue. This sort of behavior was also recently fixed in Paragraphs as well, where deleting a referenced paragraph type would also delete any field using it and all of its configuration. https://www.drupal.org/node/2468045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no undo button. Deleted configurations are deleted configurations :-(
With Drupal 8.4: It is not deleting the view anymore - it is disabling the view so you can change your view and enable it again.
[image: Drupal will no longer delete your Views]
(taken from the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2468045) Ashish mentioned above, Picture by [vaplas](https://www.drupal.org/u/vaplas))

Comment: I'm on 8.7.2 and still seeing this issue, just FYI.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's what currently happens. Drupal informs you on the delete confirmation page what all will be deleted.

You can try one thing that to restore your backed up database.

Also, there is an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2468045) that tries to improve it so that the view updates itself instead.